# setUndecorated() not working with PLAF

Tags: java, swing, jframe, look-and-feel

I am building a desktop application that requires the use of an external JFrame to house various drawing tools for the user.

Here's what my current JFrame looks like:

![enter image description here][1]

Here's the class:

```
public class ChartToolFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private JToolBar tools;

    public ChartToolFrame(JToolBar tools){
        setUndecorated(true);
        this.tools = tools;
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(tools, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        setResizable(false);
        this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        setVisible(true);
        pack();
    }

}
```

I'm currently using the Acryl look and feel. When I call setUndecorated(true) it does not get rid of the title bar. It's essential to rely on a JButton for disposing the JFrame because, upon closing, a certain "mode of operation" must terminate and code must be executed.

Is there any way to undecorate a JFrame with a non-default look and feel associated with it? Or even better, is there any way to associate a method call with the disposing of a JFrame?

Comment: *"Which leads me to believe the look and feel is culprit here."*  It seems it would be easy enough to test, rather than guess.

Answer (score 1):

The docs for [`setUndecorated(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29) clearly state..

> Disables or enables decorations for this frame.
>
> This method can only be called **while the frame is not displayable**. ..

Comment: Under what conditions is the frame not displayable? I moved the setUndecorated(true); line to the beginning of the constructor but it has no effect.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCTRE).

Comment: Note this problem likely has nothing to do with the PLAF, so don't set one in the MCTRE..

Comment: You were right, the PLAF wasn't where I had to look to solve what I needed. I edited the question. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Instead of focusing on a JButton for code execution on dispose I provided an overridden dispose() method which executes the code I need. Here's the method I added to the class ChartToolFrame:

```
@Override
public void dispose(){
   //code needed to be executed
   super.dispose();
}
```

Hope this helps someone else out there.